# password for AES Crypt document

Tags: encryption

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04. I then tried to open an encrypted document using AES Crypt, which I had previously encrypted, to find that my password did not open the document. I have opened and re-encrypted this document many times in the past with no trouble,
Could the upgrade have affected the storing of this password?
Would be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

well, I can not imagine what process of the upgrade should change personal documents, but if you would like to make sure if there was a change use "sha256sum" on you backup of the document and compare the hash with the sha256sum hash of the document in question - if they are different now.